# Jquery add to cart

Tags: jquery

I want to create macarons e-commerce website where users select macarons for a fixed box (say 1 box means 10 macarons) and add them into cart. So the scenario is, by clicking on a product from the left panel (see screen shot SS1.png), the same product will appear on the box, and so on. I have done necessary jobs through JQuery and working fine.

When the user fill the required macarons within the boxes and click on the add to cart button, the products will be added in to the cart as a 'set/ group'. So the cart will look like as per the second screen shot - SS2.png. Can you tell me how can I add the products into the cart? The site is on PHP and MySQL.

The screen shots are given below:

[image: SS1]
[image: SS2]

Awaiting your response.

Comment: have you ever tried using angular js ? I think it will make this application easier for you to implement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you are looking out for `AJAX` functionality

You can write some code like this:
I am assuming that the selected items are shown in a div with some kind of unique `Ids`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addtocartbutton').click(function() {
        // here you can loop through the div or something to get the selected items
           var quantities = {};  //creating an empty string to store the productids and quantities selected
       $('selecteditemsdiv').each(function(){
          var itemid = $(this).data('id');//get the item id assuming it is stored in the data-* attributes
          var qty = $(this).data('qty'); //get the quantity if you have stored it in data-* attributes
        just push it in the json string
           quantities['itemid'] = qty;

        });
        $.ajax({
            url: "cart.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {datainfo: quantities}, //pass the json string to php
            success: function(data) {
                // Do stuff when the AJAX call returns
            }
        });
    });
});
```